# Is there any way to use view display format to show the data in drupal 7?

Tags: 7, views

I have created a custom content type "listusers" and add fields to that content type. After that i created a view page where i select display format as "Table" now my output  is like below:

[image]

can any one suggest me is there any way to achieve the view as attached in below image
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could filter the view by the designation column to group the results. 
To separate the tables I would create different view blocks for each result and put them one after each other. You could use the block title for the Haryana/Ambala text and style it accordingly.

In the example bellow I have a view with 3 blocks and each of the blocks displays rooms tagged by a room category. 
[image]

Comment: i am getting confused.. you told me to create the different different blocks but i need a custom fields so how can i add those fields data?

Comment: What do you need a custom field for ?

Comment: like i have a custom content type and under this i am having fields like name, designation, email etc and now you told me to create three different blocks. i am confused here if i am creating a block then how can i add the data related these fields bcoz in blocks only three fields title, description and region

Comment: and one more thing like you added the filter criteria room category = prestigious location when i am trying to add there is no option. First i select the content field location and there is an options like operator equal to